# JPA catalog for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I got stuck a bit. I am using Spring Boot 2.0 with JPA

I have multiple databases configured, but this one is for MySQL.

I have Entity class annotated like this:

```
@Table(name = "someConfig", schema = "foo")
```

My JDBC URL looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://somehost:3306/?useSSL=false
```

Then I get error:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1046, SQLState: 3D000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : No database selected
```

I read that I should specify `catalog` in `@Entity`, so I made it look like:

```
@Table(name = "someConfig", schema = "foo", catalog = "foo")
```

but then IntelliJ IDEA doesn't compile it - says "cannot resolve column id, etc". I also tried removing `schema` and just going with `catalog` - same error and doesn't compile.

I know I could specify database in URL - but I have multiple databases and this is not solution. Need some other way to be able choose database. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**Update1:**
Well I could create one more JPA config for same database, but with two different URL which would differ only by database, but this is just overkill I think.